# Performance when iterating over IQueryable in c#

Tags: c#

I need to know which of this approach is faster.

```
// Approach1
var filteredList = MyList.Where(x => x.IsNull);
foreach (var item in filteredList)
{
   // Do someghing...
}

// Approach2
foreach (var item in MyList.Where(x => x.IsNull))
{
   // Do someghing...
}
```

Does the last one execute the `Where` every time the `foreach` iterates?

Comment: No, that would be ridiculous. What sense would it make to get a new iterator on each iteration?

Comment: By adding a where you are getting differed execution because you are now acting on an IEnumerable, That where condition is being checked on each iteration regardless, however if you needed to use that conditioned enumerable multiple times, it would be slightly more optimal to turn that IEnumerable back into a list

Comment: They do exactly the same

Comment: They are the same, so you won't get a difference in performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is pretty much no difference between these two.

In this version

```
// Approach1
var filteredList = MyList.Where(x => x.IsNull);
foreach (var item in filteredList)
{
   // Do someghing...
}
```

You are essentially saying

1. Get an iterator (`IEnumerable<T>`) from somewhere
2. Assign a reference to that iterator to a variable.
3. Iterate over the iterator

In this version

```
// Approach2
foreach (var item in MyList.Where(x => x.IsNull))
{
   // Do someghing...  
}
```

You are essentially saying

1. Get an iterator (`IEnumerable<T>`) from somewhere
2. Iterate over the iterator

So the difference is very slight-- the only thing additional in approach1 is assignment of a reference variable to another reference variable, which is a question of moving a few bytes in memory.

What's more, the compiler might just optimize out the variable `filteredList`, in which case it will emit exactly the same IL for both approaches.

Comment: ... which will probably be optimized away by the compiler.

Comment: *which is a question of moving four bytes in memory...* considering 32 bit machine (OS)

Comment: Which is exactly what my answer shows below @john will

Answer (score 3):

It's worth reading up [on how `foreach` works](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288257(v=vs.71).aspx) (not just for this question, but as a matter of general interest): It gets one enumerator (surprisingly broadly defined) from the result of the expression to the right of `in`, and then calls `bool MoveNext()` on that enumerator until `MoveNext()` returns false.

It would make no sense for `foreach` to repeatedly evaluate the expression it gets the enumerator from. In fact, .NET goes to great lengths to prevent you from changing a sequence while it's being enumerated -- in other words, to ensure that it's enumerating over the exact same thing it started with. Try adding an item to a `List<T>` while you're in a foreach on it:

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToList();

foreach (var x in list)
{
    list.Add(x);
}
```

> "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."

No sale.

And if it were getting new enumerators, it would have to skip items in them. First iteration, grab first item. Second: Grab a new enumerator, skip one, take next. Third: Grab a new enumerator, skip two, jump off a bridge.

That's madness. It's no way for professionals to write code, or even halfway sober amateurs.

So, it's just using the result of your expression. Doesn't matter whether the expression happens to be between the parens or not, or whether you assigned its result to a local variable.

Both versions are the same.

There's also the possibility of potentially open-ended enumerations -- something in there could be sitting on a parallel thread, queueing stuff coming in from a device driver or something, and the enumeration might not necessarily end. But you'd still be getting the same enumerator from either version of your code.

Comment: liked the example of *collection modified...*

Answer (score 2):

Check the documentation on [Enumerable.Where()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) as it quotes:

> The query represented by this method is not executed until the object
>   is enumerated either by calling its GetEnumerator method directly or
>   by using foreach in Visual C#

So essentially, there is no difference between the two approach you have posted

Answer (score 0):

Both loops are identical.

The code inside the Where() *does* execute for each and every item on MyList - you've specified it as the criteria to decide whether an element on the list should be included in the result.

So,

```
x => x.IsNull
```

executes for every element in MyList, but the body of your foreach loop:

```
// Do something
```

will only execute for those elements that pass the criteria, and it will be assigned to item. That is, for every time your foreach loop executes, the item it "sees" will have item.IsNull true.

Answer (score 0):

They are both Identical, that's the beauty of Iterators. You can also check the IL that it gets compiled down to, which is same in LINQPAD.

```
IL_0033:  ldloc.0     // list
IL_0034:  ldsfld      UserQuery+<>c.<>9__0_0
IL_0039:  dup         
IL_003A:  brtrue.s    IL_0053
IL_003C:  pop         
IL_003D:  ldsfld      UserQuery+<>c.<>9
IL_0042:  ldftn       UserQuery+<>c.<Main>b__0_0
IL_0048:  newobj      System.Func<UserQuery+Test,System.Boolean>..ctor
IL_004D:  dup         
IL_004E:  stsfld      UserQuery+<>c.<>9__0_0
IL_0053:  call        System.Linq.Enumerable.Where<Test>
IL_0058:  stloc.3     // filteredList
IL_0059:  nop         
IL_005A:  ldloc.3     // filteredList
IL_005B:  callvirt    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<UserQuery+Test>.GetEnumerator
IL_0060:  stloc.s     04 
IL_0062:  br.s        IL_0077
IL_0064:  ldloc.s     04 
IL_0066:  callvirt    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<UserQuery+Test>.get_Current
IL_006B:  stloc.s     05 // item
IL_006D:  nop         
IL_006E:  ldloc.s     05 // item
IL_0070:  call        LINQPad.Extensions.Dump<Test>
IL_0075:  pop         
IL_0076:  nop         
IL_0077:  ldloc.s     04 
IL_0079:  callvirt    System.Collections.IEnumerator.MoveNext
IL_007E:  brtrue.s    IL_0064
IL_0080:  leave.s     IL_008F
IL_0082:  ldloc.s     04 
IL_0084:  brfalse.s   IL_008E
IL_0086:  ldloc.s     04 
IL_0088:  callvirt    System.IDisposable.Dispose
IL_008D:  nop         
IL_008E:  endfinally  
IL_008F:  nop         


IL_0090:  ldloc.0     // list
IL_0091:  ldsfld      UserQuery+<>c.<>9__0_1
IL_0096:  dup         
IL_0097:  brtrue.s    IL_00B0
IL_0099:  pop         
IL_009A:  ldsfld      UserQuery+<>c.<>9
IL_009F:  ldftn       UserQuery+<>c.<Main>b__0_1
IL_00A5:  newobj      System.Func<UserQuery+Test,System.Boolean>..ctor
IL_00AA:  dup         
IL_00AB:  stsfld      UserQuery+<>c.<>9__0_1
IL_00B0:  call        System.Linq.Enumerable.Where<Test>
IL_00B5:  callvirt    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<UserQuery+Test>.GetEnumerator
IL_00BA:  stloc.s     06 
IL_00BC:  br.s        IL_00D1
IL_00BE:  ldloc.s     06 
IL_00C0:  callvirt    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<UserQuery+Test>.get_Current
IL_00C5:  stloc.s     07 // item
IL_00C7:  nop         
IL_00C8:  ldloc.s     07 // item
IL_00CA:  call        LINQPad.Extensions.Dump<Test>


void Main()
{
    List<Test> list = new List<Test>();
    var x1 = new Test() { IsNull = false };
    var x2 = new Test() { IsNull = true };
    list.Add(x1);
    list.Add(x2);
    // Approach1
    var filteredList = list.Where(x => x.IsNull == true);
    foreach (var item in filteredList)
    {
        item.Dump();
    }
    // Approach2
    foreach (var item in list.Where(x => x.IsNull == true))
    {
        item.Dump();
    }
}
```